# Как прочесть Json файл в Unity3d для Android

Tags: android, c#, unity3d

Есть следуюший код для чтения файла:

```
public void readPurchase(){
    string  path;
    #if UNITY_EDITOR
    path = "/StreamingAssets/purchase.json";
    #elif UNITY_ANDROID
    path = "jar:file://" + Application.dataPath + "!/assets/purchase.json";
    #endif

    StartCoroutine (jsonReadCorout(path));
    string json = File.ReadAllText(Application.dataPath + path);
    itemsContent = JsonUtility.FromJson<Main> (json); 
    bundleForPing = itemsContent.bundleID;
}
IEnumerator jsonReadCorout(string path){
    WWW www = new WWW(path);
    yield return www;
    {
        Debug.LogError ("Can't read");
    }
}
```

файл находится в папке StreamingAssets, у меня не правильный путь к нему но не могу понять где ошибка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё просто оказалось...

```
private IEnumerator ReloadFile(){
    WWW data = new WWW(Application.streamingAssetsPath+"/"+"purchase.json");
    yield return data;
        itemsContent = JsonUtility.FromJson<Main> (data.text); 
        bundleForPing = itemsContent.bundleID;
}
```

Файл `purchase.json` нужно ставить в папку `StreamingAssets`.